# Must build steps be Durable in order to run in parallel with Jenkins workflow?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow

I'm experimenting with the parallel step in jenkins workflow. Currently my flow looks (essentially) like this:

```
parallel 'Deploy-A-Machine': {
    node {
        input 'Shall we deploy the A machine?'
        step([$class: 'DeployMachineBuilder', deploymentName: aPodName])
    }
}, 'Deploy-B-Machine': {
    node {
        input 'Shall we deploy the B machine?'
        step([$class: 'DeployMachineBuilder', deploymentName: bPodName])
    }
}
```

Both inputs show up as running on different executors, but when I click "proceed" on both, only the first deploy actually starts. The deploys run as a custom plugin that was written for legacy jobs and converted very minimally to workflow. I don't see any obvious message about waiting for an executor, the deploy just simply doesn't start. Once the first one is finished, the second one will immediately begin.

Must I implement DurableTask (or another thing?) before the parallel step will allow both to run? My conversion so far has been very light, so maybe it's time to try for a more true conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `DeployMachineBuilder` is a `SimpleBuildStep` you have written, indeed its `perform` method will simply block the Workflow virtual machine for its duration: the Groovy interpreter uses coöperative multitasking.

The simplest solution, where feasible, is to use `sh` steps rather than a custom builder. This survives slave disconnections and/or Jenkins restarts, and displays incremental progress and works properly with `parallel`. [JENKINS-26055](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26055) would provide a more convenient way to define custom “durable” steps. [JENKINS-25879](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-25879) would provide a more convenient way to define steps which are not durable, but at least avoid blocking the native thread (so behave better in `parallel` and log incrementally).

By the way in your sample script I would recommend moving the `input` step outside of the `node` block: there is no point in hogging an executor while waiting (perhaps indefinitely) for user approval.